# How to search files from a specific time with OS X 10.5.8?

Tags: macos, mac, file-search

I’m trying to search for a file on my Mac laptop from a long time ago. I know the type of file and I now approximately the time period when it was recorded. It’s one of those Word files that was created/saved in the `Notebook Layout` (when you can record audio while you type).

Is there was a way to search for that particular type of documents that was used between certain years (like say between year 2012 and 2014)?

Comment: If your macbook has `gfind` installed, you can search that files with `gfind / -name '*.txt' -ctime -790 -ctime +60` (use the correct extension instead of `*.txt` here).

Answer (score 0):

If Spotlight is running on that Mac laptop, then you could do something like this via Spotlight [as explained here](http://osxdaily.com/2014/05/14/find-files-date-search-spotlight-mac/):

For example, this would find any files created on February 14, 2015:

```
 created: 02/14/2015
```

For example, this would find any files modified on February 14, 2015:

```
 modified: 02/14/2015
```

And if you wanted to find any files created after February 14, 2015 just prepend `>` to the date:

```
 created: >02/14/2015
```

For files created before February 14, 2015 just prepend `<` to the date:

```
 created: <02/14/2015
```

Comment: thank you so much for the great answer! Since I'm a big time dummy when it comes to this stuff, could you please be so kind as to write a command for me for searching something in Spotlight between the years of (beginning of) 2013 and (the end of) 2014, and ONLY searching for the Word files! thank you